# How to post the parameter to the php logincheck.php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

This is my simple form which contains employe name, empno, empsal and doj(date of joining). Here i'm posting the values of this form through XMLHttpRequest object through send asynchronously and updating the requestTxt in the DOM in myDiv.

Here when i pass the parameters some thing like this, i can able to get the values in php echo $empname. "is my name";

```
var params = "empname="+myname+"&empno="+myno+"&empsal="+mysal+"&empdoj="+mydoj;
```

But at the same time, if i pass it as a object, stringified i don't know why it is not printing

```
        var params = {
        "empname":myname,
        "empno":myno,
        "empsal":mysal,
        "empdoj":mydoj
    };      
    var jsonText = JSON.stringify(params);
    alert(jsonText);
```

**Here is my code**
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="windows-1252">
<title>Sample form</title>
<style>
table td{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border:1ps solid #000;
}
.hide{
    display:none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="util.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="sampleForm" id="sampleForm" action="javascript:return false;">
    <table width="40%">
        <tr>
            <td>Employee Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="empname" id="empname"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Employee No:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="empno" id="empno"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Employee salary:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="empsal" id="empsal"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Employee DOJ:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="empdoj" id="empdoj"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submitBtn" id="submitBtn1" /></td>
        </tr> 
    </table>
    <div class="hide" id="myDiv"></div>
            </form>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var subform = document.getElementById("sampleForm");
         subform.onsubmit = function(){     
    var myReq;
    var uRLTxt = "loginCheck.php";
    var myname = document.getElementById("empname").value;
    var myno = document.getElementById("empno").value;
    var mysal = document.getElementById("empsal").value;
    var mydoj = document.getElementById("empdoj").value;
    /*var params = "empname="+myname+"&empno="+myno+"&empsal="+mysal+"&empdoj="+mydoj;      */
    var params = {
        "empname":myname,
        "empno":myno,
        "empsal":mysal,
        "empdoj":mydoj
    };      
    var jsonText = JSON.stringify(params);
    alert(jsonText);
    myReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    myReq.open("POST",uRLTxt,true); 
    myReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");    
    //myReq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/JSON; charset=utf-8");        
    myReq.setRequestHeader("Content-length", jsonText.length);
    //alert(jsonText.length);
    myReq.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    myReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if(myReq.readyState == 4 && myReq.status == 200){
            var return_data = myReq.responseText;
            console.log(return_data);
            document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    myReq.send(jsonText);
    return false;
      };
        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

**Php Code - loginCheck.php**

```
<?php   
    $empname = isset($_REQUEST['empname']);
    $empno = isset($_REQUEST['empno']);
    $empsal = isset($_REQUEST['empsal']);
    $empdoj = isset($_REQUEST['empdoj']);
    echo $empname."is my name";
?>
```

Comment: do you really think anyone reads this ?

Comment: Sorry, i had given the code clearly now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use javascript alone, 
you want to specify the data you want to send in the `send()` method.

```
var params = {
        "empname":myname,
        "empno":myno,
        "empsal":mysal,
        "empdoj":mydoj
    };      
    var jsonText = JSON.stringify(params);
    myReq.send("totalJsonStr="+jsonText);
```

Decode your json string using `json_decode()` . Add this to your loginCheck.php

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST["totalJsonStr"])) {
        $jsonVal = json_decode($_POST["totalJsonStr"]);
        //If you want empname
        print $jsonVal->{'empname'} . " is my name"; }
        else { die("No Data Found"); } 
    ?>
```

Comment: I have been trying out this for some days, which did not worked. Thanks raduns, now it worked like charm.

Comment: One more thing i noticed, when i changed setRequestHeader to application/json it is saying "no data found.  myReqet.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/JSON; charset=utf-8")

Comment: If it is working with content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded , then you do not want to change the content type. If you want to check whether you are sending a valid json just check it in your php file(loginCheck.php) or go for jquery(Hamender's answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try it,

> 

```
<script language="javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script> 
  <script>
```

> ```
>  var myname = document.getElementById("empname").value;
>  var myno = document.getElementById("empno").value;
>  var mysal = document.getElementById("empsal").value;
>  var mydoj = document.getElementById("empdoj").value;
>
>
>  var subform = document.getElementById("sampleForm");
>       subform.onsubmit = function(){   
>     $.ajax({
>   url: 'loginCheck.php', //This is the current doc
>   type: "POST",
>   dataType:'json', // add json datatype to get json
>   data:"empname=myname&empno=myno&empsal=mysal&empdoj=mydoj",
>   success: function(data){        alert(data);        })
>    },    });      };
>  </script>
> ```

Comment: It is working with jQuery, but i need a solution for normal javascript XMLHttpRequest request

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP looks like this:

```
<?php   
    $empname = isset($_REQUEST['empname']);
    $empno = isset($_REQUEST['empno']);
    $empsal = isset($_REQUEST['empsal']);
    $empdoj = isset($_REQUEST['empdoj']);
    echo $empname."is my name";
?>
```

But the function **isset()** only returns true or false, depending if a variable is set or not. Your script should look like:

```
<?php
    // Repeat for all variables
    // This is an equivalent to:
    // if (isset($_REQUEST['empname'])) {
    //     $empname = $_REQUEST['empname'];
    // }
    // else {
    //     $empname = "";
    // }
    $empname = isset($_REQUEST['empname']) ? $_REQUEST['empname'] : "";

    echo "{$empname} is my name";
?>
```

For your params string in Javascript, change this:

```
var params = {
    "empname":myname,
    "empno":myno,
    "empsal":mysal,
    "empdoj":mydoj
};      
var jsonText = JSON.stringify(params);
alert(jsonText);

// Blah blah...

myReq.send(jsonText);
```

for this:

```
var params = {
    "empname":myname,
    "empno":myno,
    "empsal":mysal,
    "empdoj":mydoj
};
var out = new Array();

for (key in params) {
    out.push(key + "=" + encodeURI(params[key]));
}   
var postText = out.join("&");
alert(postText);

// Blah blah...

myReq.send(postText);
```

Comment: I still get the empty string for the empname

Comment: Look at the updated answer, you are sending JSON through POST, but you have to send HTTP key-value strings (key1=value1&key2=value2&...).